# ggsurvfit package cannot be installed

Tags: r, r-package, ggsurvfit

I was able to install ggsurvfit package, but was not able to library it. I pasted all information below.

> install.packages("ggsurvfit")

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\CH225175\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpk323Ys\downloaded_packages’

> library(ggsurvfit)

Error in library(ggsurvfit) : there is no package called ‘ggsurvfit’

Comment: Are you sure you installed it; it says the source code was downloaded but perhaps it wasn't compiled? Do you have a compiler ([Rtools43](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html)) installed?

Comment: @jared_mamrot, thank you so much for your help. I think you are right. ggsurvfit was not installed because I tried to install it through GitHub but it failed. I just installed Rtools43 through [https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html], but it still shows warning messages "Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed" when I tried to install ggsurvfit. Do you know what else I should do to install ggsurvfit properly? Why is this package so difficult to install?

Comment: @jared_mamrot, I finally install ggsurvfit.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem @user23097547 

Answer (score 1):

For those who cannot install ggsurvfit package properly, here are the steps that helped me to install it:

1. download RTools 4.0 at [https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html]
2. Run the following code in RStudio:
   write('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}//usr//bin;${PATH}"', file = "~/.Renviron", append = TRUE)
3. Check if "make.exe" exists: Sys.which("make")
4. install.packages("ggsurvfit") in RStudio